# Meaning of "Total work" for build indexes during load

Tags: db2, db2-luw, load

I don't think I ever reflected about it, but I'm currently loading a table from a cursor and list utilities show:

```
  Phase Number               = 3
  Description                = BUILD
  Total Work                 = 46 indexes
  Completed Work             = 0 indexes
  Start Time                 = Not Started
```

In the current schema, there are 4 indexes + an XML column (which seems to contribute with 2 according to syscat.indexes). At first I thought it might be a bug counting indexes for the same table name in different schemas, but that does not count up either, since there are 10 schemas with a table named like that.

I'm just curious what the "Total Work" means for this phase?

Comment: Is the database or the table partitioned? Is the table column-organized?

Comment: I think you can self-answer, as you know all the details.

Comment: Will do once my internet connection resurrects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you feel really stupid... The purpose of the load process is to migrate a table to range partitioning. Somehow, I managed to ignore the fact that the target table is now partitioned:

```
db2 -x "select DATAPARTITIONNAME from syscat.datapartitions where tabname = ...
P2013
P2014
...
P2023
```

This explains the number of indexes and I'll make this an answer even though it probably is of limited use for anyone else.